Under what circumstances can a school confiscate my hoodie?
The administrator had walked into the class and talked about something he was planning to do next week in front of the class. He says that if a student has their hood on during class or in  the halls they will start confiscating it for five days. So if they were to confiscate it on Monday, the student won't get it back until Friday. Do I have a say in keeping my hoodie or can they really do this?

Are you prohibited from wearing the hoodie at all, or just from having the hood over your head?

In what jurisdiction are you going to school?

It is not just schools: there are examples of shopping malls which ban hoodies with the hood up, including hoodies sold there.  They would not confiscate your hoodie, but would instead remove you from the area they control.

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/43875/how-long-are-schools-allowed-to-confiscate-items-from-students

Is this a government school or a private school?

Schools often have quite a bit of latitude, because they're acting in loco parentis while you're in class. I also expect they've notified the parents of all students of this policy, and it has been approved by the school board (it may even have been instituted by the school board, not the administrator on their own).
You've been given adequate warning about the policy, so you have a say. If you don't want them taking your hoodie, don't put the hood over your head while in class. If you're cold and need an extra layer you can wear it with the hood down.
I don't think this would generally be considered theft. In most jurisdictions, theft requires permanently depriving someone of their property. Taking it for just 5 days is not permanent.
Hoodie bans are not uncommon in schools. You can find justifications at Why Hoodies Aren't Allowed in School? It's likely that the ban was discussed at a school board meeting, which is when community members have the opportunity to make their opinions known. If you wanted to provide input, that's when you could have "had your say".

I think the expression 'you have a say' doesn't work here if OP is only informed of the rules. They are aware of them, but having a say requires at a minimum asking for feedback and usually some involvement in the decision.

They don't have a say in the policy, but they have a say in whether their hoodie is taken, since they can choose not to violate the policy.

@quarague I added some material about having a say during the political process that instituted the ban.

You are twisting the words here. The school has a policy and the student just has to obey the policy, regardless of whether they think it is a reasonable policy or not. If you follow the rules and therefore not get punished that does not mean you have a say about the rules.

@quarague: I've seen more than one case of the student ignoring the dress code with the backing of the student's parents.

"Taking it for just 5 days is not permanent." If I take your car for 5 days without permission, surely that's theft? :P

@HolyBlackCat Not if it was towed because you were parked in a no-parking zone.

@quarague They had a political say when the policy was being created. Now they have a say in whether they violate the policy.

@HolyBlackCat In England taking a car for five days without the intention to keep it longer wouldn't be theft, but I think it would would be the criminal offence of taking a vehicle without owner's consent (twoccing / joyriding) and the civil wrong of trespass to chattels.

@bdsl And of course there's that "without consent" part. In the case of the school, the student has to hand over the hoodie, and they were informed ahead of time about this. Similarly, if a school has a "no cellphones" policy, they may confiscate it for the rest of the day.

@Barmar I don't see any of that as amounting to consent from the student to have their phone taken away.

@bdsl In general, if you're informed, "if you do X, we'll do Y", and you do X, you're effectively consenting to Y happening. If you park in a private lot, with a sign saying "violators will be towed", you can't complain that they took your car without your consent.

@Barmar I'm not convinced by that argument, I don't think it's productive to continue discussing in comments though.
